# How to make ConcurrentHashMap.entrySet().removeIf operation thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, concurrenthashmap

I have to make 2 operations on ConcurrentHashMap thread safe.

Preferred option is to not to use any external locking and take advantage of ConcurrentHashMap internal locking.

However, I am not very sure that the requirement which we have can be made threadsafe without using some external locking.

we have 2 major operations :

```
 SomeObject getSomeObject(SomeParam key) {

        concurrentHaspMap.putIfAbsent(key, new SomeObject());
        return concurrentHaspMap.get(key);
    }



     void removeSomeObject() {
        if (concurrentHaspMap.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        concurrentHaspMap.entrySet().removeIf(cacheEntry -> cacheEntry.getValue().isValid() == false);
    }
```

As per my research, the removeIf map is not synchronized, and thus the condition which I might get might not be valid when we remove.

If my understanding correct?
And what is the  best way to make it threadsafe?